# Groups of Order 360

Tags: finite-groups, sylow-theory, solvable-groups

Show that every solvable group of order $360$ has a subgroup of order 90.  (This is straightforward if you use the Philip Hall theorems.  Is there an easy proof that doesn't use them?)

Comment: What "Hall theorems"?

Comment: The results analogous to Sylow's theorems for finite solvable groups, where a single prime $p$ is replaced by a set of primes.